# ContentControl not showing Content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, contentcontrol

I have a custom `ContentControl` which has a fixed XAML layout like a `UserControl` (Rather than the usual applied generic template).

Previously this layout had no extra markup, so it was literally:

```
<ContentControl x:Class="MyControls.CustomViewControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
</ContentControl>
```

This worked fine.

I now want to put a border around the content, so I have changed the XAML to:

```
<ContentControl x:Class="MyControls.CustomViewControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="LightGreen">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

This shows the border, but no content.

I tried supplying an explicit binding for ContentPresenter:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

But this made no difference.

Setting an explicit `Content` does work:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="TEST" />
```

Anyone know why the Content binding doesn't work? I guess I could fall back to the usual generic template but it would be easier if I could just do it directly like a UserControl.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add TargetType for Control Template

```
<ContentControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate  TargetType="Button">
        <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="LightGreen">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentControl.Template>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! In my case, it's an Application Style instead of ContentControl. Still the same.

Answer (score 4):

Use `TemplateBinding` instead of `Binding` inside a `ControlTemplate` :

```
<ContentControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="LightGreen">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentControl.Template>
```

EDIT:

The important part of the shown code snippet is the `TargetType` in the definition of the `ControlTemplate`. With the target type

```
<ContentControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="LightGreen">
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentControl.Template>
```

already works without any `TemplateBinding`

Comment: This didn't work, but it pointed me in the right direction since I then got an error. I needed to set the TargetType of my template. When I do this I don't need any binding at all since it's implicit. Cheers.